# Stackoverflow exception when comparing two dynamic types

Tags: haskell, dynamic, equals

I have defined a data type *Loc* which can accept Dynamics in the constructor. Moreover I need to compare *Loc* datatypes using == operator. So I came up with something like this:

```
data Loc = UnknownLoc | DynamicLoc Dynamic deriving (Eq,Show)
instance Eq Dynamic
data DynamicLocation = Loc_1 | Loc_2 deriving (Eq,Show)
instance Typeable DynamicLocation
```

But when attempting to run the following line I get stackoverflow exception.

```
DynamicLoc (toDyn Loc_1) == DynamicLoc (toDyn Loc_1)
```

any idea?

Comment: You need to read about `StateT` monad transformer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, read your compiler warnings :) You haven't provided a definition for the `Typeable` typeclass's `typeOf` method for `DynamicLocation`, and `toDyn` calls `typeOf`. So this definitely shouldn't work -- if you try just `toDyn Loc_1`, you'll get an exception.

But why an infinite loop? It's because you also haven't defined `(==)` for `Dynamic`, and `(==)` and `(/=)` are defined in terms of each other in `GHC.Classes`. GHC doesn't attempt to resolve such infinite recursion in default method declarations, so you unfortunately don't get a warning.

What to do? I suggest letting GHC derive the `Typeable` instance for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, DeriveDataTypeable #-}

data DynamicLocation = Loc_1 | Loc_2 deriving (Eq,Show)
deriving instance Typeable DynamicLocation
```

or, more sensible:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
data DynamicLocation = Loc_1 | Loc_2 deriving (Eq,Show,Typeable)
```

However, as a commenter has already pointed out, it's not immediately clear how to define `(==)` for `Dynamic`, or if this is even possible.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Haskell. can you give me a hint on how I can provide definition for typeOf method?

Comment: Fixnum - Regrading your second paragraph, also it is unlikely that a good (hand coded) definition of (==) exists for Dynamic.